# Text Search across multiple fields MySQL

Tags: mysql

I have a MySQL table laid out like this:

```
ID | Artist | Title
```

Which contains song information obtained from MP3 ID3 tags.

Now, I would like to be able to run a search on this, however the incoming data could be in a variety of formats. I'm sure you all know how ID3 tags can end up after a couple of people have had hold of them.

I have the following query which I have tried, but looking at it now, I understand completely why it doesnt bring back a result set. I'm fresh out of ideas.

```
SELECT CONCAT(artist, ' ',title) as trackname 
FROM sound_tracklist 
WHERE CONCAT(artist,' ',title) LIKE '%[JunkTags]Artist - Title[More Junk - www.junkwebsite.com]%'
```

I'd appreciate any input/direction on this.

Thanks

Comment: You'll need a more robust search mechanism than `LIKE '%string%'`. For instance, try splitting your search term into words and run searches on each word.

Answer (score 10, accepted):

If you're in MyISAM type tables, try using a FULLTEXT index:

```
ALTER TABLE sound_tracklist ADD FULLTEXT INDEX (artist, title);
```

then you can do

```
SELECT artist, title FROM sound_tracklist WHERE MATCH (artist, title) AGAINST ('bach brandenburg concerto')
```

it wouldn't catch misspellings ("konshertoe", anyone?), but it would search for your specified keyboards across all the fields in the index, and catch them in any order.

Comment: 'keyboards'? Sheesh... I really need to sleep more.