# is it possible to search in mysql or PHP or CODEIGNITER a multiple words displaying a multiple possible result

Tags: php, mysql, codeigniter

i have table in sql

employee table

```
ID firstname  lastname      bandname
------------------------------------
 1 John       Lennon        Beatles
 2 Paul       Mccartney     Beatles
 3 Ringo      Starr         Beatles
 4 George     Harrison      Beatles
```

now if i searched "George Mccartney" ,the result should be the row with the ID of 4 and 2

or if searched "1 Paul Starr" , the result should be 3 rows containing of those three words.

Comment: Split the string and check appropriate columns

Comment: @Hanky웃Panky what if the user inputted a word that is not in order like "Lennon 3 Harrison"

Comment: my answer ignores order, it just works because it's using `LIKE` to match anything similar

Answer (score 2, accepted):

[sqlFiddle example](http://sqlfiddle.com/#!2/4cbc6/6/3)

```
SET @search = '1 Paul Starr';

SELECT *
FROM employee
WHERE @search LIKE CONCAT('%',id,'%')
   OR @search LIKE CONCAT('%',firstname,'%')
   OR @search LIKE CONCAT('%',lastname,'%');
```

replace @search with your PHP code as I am not familiar with PHP.

### UPDATED ANSWER: to allow searching for substring for searches like:

"Geor" to return 1 row of "George"
  "Geor Pau" to return 2 rows of "George" and "Paul"
[sqlFiddle example](http://sqlfiddle.com/#!2/4cbc6/39/1)

```
SELECT *
FROM employee
WHERE 
          id LIKE CONCAT('%',SUBSTRING_INDEX(@search,' ',1),'%')
       OR id LIKE CONCAT('%',SUBSTRING_INDEX(SUBSTRING_INDEX(@search,' ',2),' ',-1),'%')
       OR id LIKE CONCAT('%',SUBSTRING_INDEX(SUBSTRING_INDEX(@search,' ',3),' ',-1),'%')
OR firstname LIKE CONCAT('%',SUBSTRING_INDEX(@search,' ',1),'%')
OR firstname LIKE CONCAT('%',SUBSTRING_INDEX(SUBSTRING_INDEX(@search,' ',2),' ',-1),'%')
OR firstname LIKE CONCAT('%',SUBSTRING_INDEX(SUBSTRING_INDEX(@search,' ',3),' ',-1),'%')
 OR lastname LIKE CONCAT('%',SUBSTRING_INDEX(@search,' ',1),'%')
 OR lastname LIKE CONCAT('%',SUBSTRING_INDEX(SUBSTRING_INDEX(@search,' ',2),' ',-1),'%')
 OR lastname LIKE CONCAT('%',SUBSTRING_INDEX(SUBSTRING_INDEX(@search,' ',3),' ',-1),'%')
;
```

or if you prefer the below does the same thing using `LOCATE` (much shorter query)
[sqlFiddle example](http://sqlfiddle.com/#!2/4cbc6/46/1)

```
SELECT *
FROM employee
WHERE 
   LOCATE(SUBSTRING_INDEX(@search,' ',1)                        ,CONCAT(id,firstname,lastname))>0
OR LOCATE(SUBSTRING_INDEX(SUBSTRING_INDEX(@search,' ',2),' ',-1),CONCAT(id,firstname,lastname))>0
OR LOCATE(SUBSTRING_INDEX(SUBSTRING_INDEX(@search,' ',3),' ',-1),CONCAT(id,firstname,lastname))>0
;
```

Comment: i was wondering what if my table has another column (bandname) and the value is "Beatles" .. now i searched only this "George Beatles". the result is 4 rows. which it should be only 1 row containing George harrison

Comment: can you update your question to reflect that data as I am unsure if all your rows contain Beatles or just one?

Comment: I see you've updated the question so all 4 rows contain 'Beatles' now do you want to search on bandname or not if not just don't add the `LIKE CONCAT('%',bandname,'%')`

Comment: oh i see. then what if i add another one with same name "George Harrison" but the bandname is different?

Comment: Also the @search. can that be set like this? 
and i dont have the set $param then
"SELECT *
FROM employee
WHERE @".$variable." LIKE CONCAT('%',id,'%')"

Comment: remove the @ and probably add single quotes around $variable like `... WHERE '".$variable."' LIKE CONCAT ...` you might want to escape your $variable too to prevent SQL injections (by hackers) not too sure how to do that though i have heard it mentioned many times.

Comment: I'm going to try it now. Just got back to office.

Comment: @Vincent, if you want "Geor" to return 1 row of "George" and "pau" to return 1 row of "Paul" and "Geor Pau" to return 2 rows of "George" and "Paul", see my updated answer at bottom this works when user enters 1 search term up to maximum of 3 search terms

Answer (score 2):

```
$search="1 Paul Starr";
list($id,$fn,$ln)=explode(" ",$search);

/*
 Sanitize these values or prepare the query. An example could be
 Remember, if you neither sanitize these values nor use prepared statements, its
 Dangerous!
*/


$query="SELECT * FROM yourTABLE 
        WHERE ID=$id
        OR firstname LIKE '%$fn%'
        OR lastname LIKE '%$ln%' ";

 // Or better use Prepared statements
```

**Edit**

Ok so they can be in any order? Then you can do

```
$search="1 Paul Starr";
list($v1,$v2,$v3)=explode(" ",$search);

//Sanitize, Remember?


 $query="SELECT * FROM yourTABLE 
    WHERE ID IN ('$v1','$v2','$v3')
    OR firstname IN ('$v1','$v2','$v3')
    OR lastname IN ('$v1','$v2','$v3')";
```

Comment: what if it is not in order? like john 1 starr?

Comment: There has to be a pattern, no magic for computer to know what is first name what is last name if you have them in arbitrary order without any pattern

Comment: oh i get it. now here's another problem. what if my first name has two names and last name also. like John Paul De la Cruz?

Comment: @Hanky웃Panky I dont think he means that the computer has to be able to see what the last name and first name are. I think he just wants to check it all even if the order is messed up.

Comment: Ok @Loko so can you tell me a way to tell that to Computer? sometimes there will be 4 words, sometimes 2 sometimes 3 sometimes 1 sometimes 5 and those too in an arbitrary order, lets create a pattern for computer to tell what amongst them is first name and what is last name. Its much harder than it looks. There has to be a pattern

Comment: @Hanky웃Panky I think you are thinkin too difficult. I can't think of it now since I am never using it but I made something like this(It's on my hdd which I cant have access to at the moment. If he types in:"Mccartney John" he wants to show 1 and 2. I dont see how that is very hard.

Comment: @Loko nope I think you missed some of the communication above. He also wants support for this `John Paul De la Cruz`. You tell me how to tell a computer which part is first and which is last

Comment: @Hanky웃Panky Ok I see, but that was before you said that would be magic. Anyway when he searches for John Paul De la Cruz does he want to show John lennon?

Answer (score 2):

try using a FULLTEXT index,something like this:

```
ALTER TABLE employee ADD FULLTEXT INDEX (ID,firstname,lastname);
```

then you can do

```
SELECT ID,firstname,lastname    
FROM employee          
WHERE MATCH (ID,firstname,lastname) AGAINST ('1 Paul Starr')
```

take a look here [Text Search across multiple fields MySQL](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5654910/text-search-across-multiple-fields-mysql)

Comment: interesting, do you know why I can't uncomment the ALTER TABLE line? [sqlFiddle](http://sqlfiddle.com/#!2/8ae51d/2/0) here, it saysThe used table type doesn't support FULLTEXT indexes is it just sqlFiddle that doesn't allow it?

Comment: Full-text indexes can be used only with MyISAM tables.see here http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.5/en/fulltext-search.html

Comment: i got this error Can't find FULLTEXT index matching the column list

Comment: i used a XAMP for this

Comment: @Vincent did you try my answer?

Answer (score 1):

Might be a better way but here you've got an example:

```
SELECT id, firstname, lastname 
FROM employee      
WHERE firstname = 'input_name' 
   OR lastname = 'input_lastname'
```

Comment: what if it is not in order? like john 1 starr?

Answer (score 1):

```
$a="George Mccartney";
$name=explode(" ",$a);

$query="select * from employee
       where firstname like '%$name[0]%' 
        or 
       firstname like '%$name[1]%' 
       or lastname like '%$name[0]%' 
       or lastname like '%$name[1]%'
        ";
```

when you are not sure of the user input like `"1 Paul Starr"` than you may do as under:

```
 $a="George Mccartney hghh hghh ....whatever";
 $name=explode(" ",$a);
 $count=count($name);
   for($i=0;$i<$count;$i++)
   {
           $query="select * from employee
           where firstname like '%$name[i]%' 
            or 
           lastname like '%$name[i]%'
            or 
           id='$name[i]' ";

         -----your code to print the output or take the output in array----
   }
```

Comment: what if it is not in order? like john 1 starr?

Comment: thats y i took two like statement that will match the pattern for both firstname and lastname or better you can use a for loop to check for all possible cases

Comment: and what about the ID?

Comment: @Hanky웃Panky i think the OP wants to fetch the row using names and not id

Comment: `or if searched "1 Paul Starr" , the result should be 3 rows containing of those three words.`